# Possible params for /{user-id}/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I am doing some proof-of-concept with Facebook SDK and Graph API to list user's posts using the [/me/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed). I am unable to find a reference where I can see the list of possible options that can be passed as parameters.

For example, how can one find only those posts that are made within a specific time range? or how to retrieve only public posts shared by the user>

Could someone please help me by listing all the possible filters?

Answer (score 1):

For getting data in a specific time range, take a look at time based cursors: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.6#paging

`/me/posts` would be the endpoint to get posts shared by the user only. It´s explained in the links you posted.